# query scrollTo does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

I'm using the scrollTo jquery library in a page I'm building, and it works with Chrome, Safari, and IE 8/9, but not with firefox. Firebug tells me,

TypeError: $("#wrapper").scrollTo is not a function

Here is the line that includes the scrollTo library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
```

Here is the function where I use scrollTo

```
function scrollPage(currentpage,scrollpage) {
    $(scrollpage).find('.text').fadeOut();
    $(currentpage).find('.text').fadeOut( function(){
        $('#wrapper').scrollTo( scrollpage, 1500, {
            onAfter:function(){
                $(scrollpage).find('.text').fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Why would firefox not think scrollTo was a function, while all other browsers I've tried do?

EDIT: It seems that my files work on other computers, but not on my current install of firefox. I am going to re-install and see that helps.

Comment: Maybe a popup blocker... see here: https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2202

Comment: That it was. Kaspersky installed a security add on in firefox, and was blocking scrollTo. Thanks. If you want to edit your original answer, I will mark it as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION:

Well, it seems a popup blocker caused a conflict! The OP found that Kaspersky installed a security add on in firefox, and was blocking scrollTo.

More: http://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2202

ORIGINAL POST:

I sometimes get that error when my jQuery code is not enclosed in a `$(document).ready(function() {...your jquery statements here ...});`  block.

Your function doesn't have to be inside doc ready but the statement that calls it should be.

Comment: The function is not inside doc ready, but the statement  that calls the function is. I tried moving the function in there, for good measures, and still having the error.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5EwN/)). Did you include jQuery in your html?

This is how you can do it (BEFORE your ScrollTo library, of course):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I did include jQuery before scrollTo

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using scrollTo I used scrollIntoView and it worked in FireFox, Chrome and IE.

Example :

```
var element = document.querySelector('.navbar-brand');
element.scrollIntoView();
```