# scrollTo() working well in chrome but not working in firefox

Tags: javascript

I m trying to use scrollTo() in my script but is not working in firefox while it is smoothly working in chrome

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.scroll').click( function(){
            var location = "." + $(this).attr("id");
            $("body,html").scrollTo(location,100);        
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: try `window.scrollTo(location,100)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [query scrollTo does not work in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054194/query-scrollto-does-not-work-in-firefox)

Comment: i already tried  that all the solutions but not any of them is able to solve it

Comment: Seems like it wouldn't do anything as it's written now. Wouldn't location end up being `".some-id"`?

Comment: Working [fine](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zXLdxG) for me with Firefox. Assuming you're using the plugin. Why not use `window` though.

Comment: actually i have radio buttons and on the click og them i m performing scrolling accordingly.Further it is perfectly working in chrome but dont know why not in mozilla

Comment: here is my site you may take a look http://foodver.esy.es/